# Hovers acting slow?

Tags: css, hover

Is it just me or are my hovers acting slow?

Which hover? - http://bitacora-fotografica.tumblr.com

> Menu left, after clicking throw a link visited goes black and link should now turn initial light pink when mouse on hover.

**CODE:**

```
<head>
<title>{Title}</title>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{Favicon}">
<meta name="color:background" content="#ffffff"/>
<meta name="color:text" content="#000000"/>
<meta name="color:link" content="#888888"/>
<meta name="color:hover" content="#000000"/>
<meta name="color:permalinks" content="#ffffff"/>
<meta name="color:permalinks text" content="#000000"/>
<meta name="color:post permalinks" content="#6683D4" />
<meta name="font:body" content="Geneva" />
<meta name="font:post permalinks" content="Georgia" />
<meta name="image:background" content=""/>
<meta name="if:photo shadow" content="0"/>
<meta name="if:rounded photos" content="0"/>
<meta name="if:transparent content" content="1"/>
<meta name="if:fade in follow" content="1"/>
<meta name="if:faded images" content="0"/>
<meta name="if:animated post load" content="0"/>
<meta name="text:navigation title" content="navigate" />
<meta name="text:home link title" content="home" />
<meta name="text:message link title" content="message" />
<meta name="text:link one" content="" />
<meta name="text:link one title" content="" />
<meta name="text:link two" content="" />
<meta name="text:link two title" content="" />
<meta name="text:link three" content="" />
<meta name="text:link three title" content="" />
<meta name="text:link four" content="" />
<meta name="text:link four title" content="" />

<style type="text/css">
iframe#tumblr_controls{
margin-top:3px;
position:fixed !important;
{block:iffadeinfollow}
opacity:0.7;-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
{/block:iffadeinfollow}
}

iframe#tumblr_controls:hover{
{block:iffadeinfollow}
opacity:1;-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
{/block:iffadeinfollow}
}

body{
margin:0px;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: repeat;
background-color:{color:background};
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: repeat;
background-image:url('{image:background}');
font-family:{font:body};
line-height:9px;
color: {color:text};
}

a:link, a:active{
color: {color:link};
text-decoration: none;
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover{
color: {color:hover};
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical {
    background-color:{color:link};
    height:10px;width:10px;opacity:0.5;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;border:2px #ffffff solid;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
    background-color:{color:link};opacity:0.5;
    height:10px !important;border:2px #ffffff solid;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
}

/* PERMALINK VARIABLES */

.entry #shadow{opacity:1;{block:ifnotphotoshadow}opacity:0;{/block:ifnotphotoshadow}margin-left:0px;bottom:-20px;position:absolute;width:250px;background-color:transparent;height:auto;z-index:100;}.entry#shadow img{width:250px;}

 .tweek{
    margin-left:775px;
    width:200px;
    padding:2px;
    background-color:white;
{block:iftransparentcontent}
background-color:transparent;
{/block:iftransparentcontent}
    position:fixed;
    height:100%;
    z-index:10;
}

.entry:hover #container{
bottom:45%;{block:permalinkpage}opacity:0;visibility:hidden;{/block:permalinkpage}
opacity:1;-webkit-transition-duration:0.4s;
    -webkit-transition:0.4s;
}

#posts .entry {
margin:10px;
float:left;
padding-top:3px;
padding-right:4px;
padding-left:130px;
padding-bottom:0px;
width:250px;
background-color:transparent;
font-family:{font:body};
font-size: 9px;
line-height:14px;
{block:permalinkpage}

{/block:permalinkpage}
{block:ifanimatedpostload}
-webkit-transition-duration:2s;
{/block:ifanimatedpostload}
}

#posts{
    padding-top:30px;
    padding-left:55px;

}

.entry #text a{font-family:{font:post permalinks};color:{color:post permalinks};}

.entry #text{
text-align:center;
font-family:{font:post permalinks};
letter-spacing:0px;
opacity:1;
text-transform:lowercase;
font-size:9px;
text-decoration:underline;
color:{color:post permalinks};-webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
}

.entry .cooper{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:4px;
    right:7px;
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:8px;
    border-radius:45px;
    font-family:courier new;
    background-color:white;
    z-index:100;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-out;transition: all 1s ease-out;{block:permalinkpage}visibility:hidden;{/block:permalinkpage}
}

.entry:hover .cooper{
    bottom:7px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
opacity:0.7;{block:permalinkpage}visibility:hidden;{/block:permalinkpage}
}

.entry .cooper a{color:{color:link};font-size:8px;{block:permalinkpage}visibility:hidden;{/block:permalinkpage}}

.entry .j{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:4px;
    right:35px;
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    background-image:url('http://www.clker.com/cliparts/X/I/V/b/z/E/heart-th.png');
    background-size:17px 17px;
    background-position:center 5px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:9px;
    border-radius:55px;
    line-height:26px;
    font-family:courier new;
    background-color:white;
    z-index:1;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-out;transition: all 1s ease-out;{block:permalinkpage}visibility:hidden;{/block:permalinkpage}
}

.entry:hover .j{
    bottom:7px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
opacity:0.7;{block:permalinkpage}visibility:hidden;{/block:permalinkpage}
}

.entry .j img{width:17px;height:17px;margin-top:5px;{block:permalinkpage}visibility:hidden;{/block:permalinkpage}}

.entry .j a{color:{color:link};font-size:9px;{block:permalinkpage}visibility:hidden;{/block:permalinkpage}}

.entry .jill{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:4px;
    right:63px;
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    background-image:url('http://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/brightmix/128/monotone_search_zoom.png');
    background-size:24px 24px;
    background-position:0px 1px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:9px;
    border-radius:55px;
    line-height:26px;
    font-family:courier new;
    background-color:white;
    z-index:100;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-out;transition: all 1s ease-out;{block:permalinkpage}visibility:hidden;{/block:permalinkpage}
}

.entry:hover .jill{
    bottom:7px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
opacity:0.7;{block:permalinkpage}visibility:hidden;{/block:permalinkpage}
}

.entry .jill img{width:17px;height:17px;margin-top:5px;{block:permalinkpage}visibility:hidden;{/block:permalinkpage}}

.entry .jill a{color:{color:link};font-size:9px;{block:permalinkpage}visibility:hidden;{/block:permalinkpage}}

div#relative-header{
text-align:justify;
background-color:white;
{block:iftransparentcontent}
background-color:transparent;
{/block:iftransparentcontent}
margin-left:-80px;
top:35px;
font-family:{font:body};
font-size: 9px;
width: 260px;
padding:2px;
height:auto;
opacity:1;
z-index:100;
position:absolute;
overflow: scroll;
}

div#relative-header a{color:{color:link};margin-left:5px;display:inline-block;}

.tweeked{{block:iffadeinfollow}opacity:0.7;-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;transition: all 0.5s ease-out;{/block:iffadeinfollow}
    -webkit-animation:  fadeInUp 3s;-moz-animation:  fadeInUp  3s;-ms-animation:fadeInUp 3s;position: fixed !important;z-index: 5;left: 3px;bottom: 3px;width: 80px;background: #888;font-family: georgia;font-size: 9px;padding-top: 3px;padding-bottom: 3px;-moz-border-radius: 3px;border-radius: 3px;color:#fff;text-align:center;z-index:99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999;
    }

    .tweeked:hover{{block:iffadeinfollow}opacity:1;{/block:iffadeinfollow}-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;transition: all 0.5s ease-out;}





.chat li.odd{padding-left:3px;width:250px;margin-left:0px;color:{color:text};background-color: {color:transparent};}.chat li.even{padding-left:3px;color:{color:text};background-color: #E3E3E3;}

.title{font-family:{font:body};font-size:10px;line-height:3px;}

blockquote{padding-left:3px;padding-right:3px;margin-left:0px;background-color:#E9E9E9;width:240px;border-left: 2px solid {color:link};border-right: 2px solid {color:link};overflow:auto;text-align:justify;{block:permalinkpage}width:800px;margin-left:0px;{/block:permalinkpage}}

.img{{block:iffadedimages}opacity:0.75;{/block:iffadedimages}{block:ifnotfadedimages}opacity:1;{/block:ifnotfadedimages}background-color:white;-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;transition: all 0.5s ease-out;}

img{{block:ifroundedphotos}border-radius:5px;{/block:ifroundedphotos}}

 #base{
     width:280px;
 }

 #base a{display:block;color:{color:link};-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;-moz-transition: all 1s ease-out;transition: all 1s ease-out;padding-top:10px;}
 .rent {
     margin-top:3px;
     text-transform:initial;
     letter-spacing:1px;
     font-family:{font:body};
     font-size:10px;}
/* normal state */

.blogtitle a{text-align:right;color:{color:link};width:auto;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease;-moz-transition: all 1s ease;-o-transition: all 1s ease;transition: all 1s ease;}
.blogtitle:hover a{color:{color:hover};width:auto;-webkit-transition: all 1s ease;-moz-transition: all 1s ease;-o-transition: all 1s ease;transition: all 1s ease;text-align:right;}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

p.down{
     font-size:9px;
     color:#b05845;
     margin-top:3px;
 }

#relative-header a:visited {
    color: #000000;}

#relative-header  a:hover{
color: {color:hover};
}

.rightmenu{

text-align:justify;
background-color:white;
{block:iftransparentcontent}
background-color:transparent;
{/block:iftransparentcontent}
margin-left:1000px;
top:30px;
font-family:{font:body};
font-size: 9px;
width: 150px;
padding:2px;
height:auto;
opacity:1;
z-index:100;
position:fixed;
line-height:14px;
}

.rightmenu a:hover{

color: {color:hover};
}
.rightmenu a:visited{

color:#000000;
}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.tumblr.com/7qdgtio/iQPmcn41r/likedbyunimpulsive.txt"></script>
<div class="tweeked"><a href="http://unimpulsive.tumblr.com/"><font color="#ffffff">unimpulsive theme</font></a></div>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{Favicon}">
<!-- END HTML/NO-REMOVE -->

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$('li.drawer div:nth-child(2)').hide();
$('li.drawer h4').click(function () {
if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
$('li.drawer div:visible:nth-child(2)').slideUp().prev().removeClass('open');}
else {
$('li.drawer div:visible:nth-child(2)').slideUp().prev().removeClass('open');
$(this).next().slideDown();
$(this).addClass('open');}
});
});
</script>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Julius+Sans+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.tumblr.com/dbek3sy/iBElrgjim/jquerymasonry.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.tumblr.com/dbek3sy/Qyblrgjfn/jqueryinfintescroll.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
        deeplinking: false,
        default_width: 600,
        default_height: 550,
        allow_resize: true,
  });
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function () {
var $content = $('#posts');
$content.masonry({itemSelector: '.entry'}),
$content.infinitescroll({
navSelector : 'div#pagination',
nextSelector : 'div#pagination a#nextPage',
itemSelector : '.entry',
loading: {/*♑*/
finishedMsg: '',
img: 'http://www.bernardbb2.com/tiki/spryAssets/b2/loading_transparent.gif'
},
bufferPx : 200,
debug : false,
},
// call masonry as a callback.
function( newElements ) {
var $newElems = $( newElements );
$newElems.hide();
// ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
$newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
$content.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true, function(){$newElems.fadeIn(1500);} );
});
});
});
</script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
$("p").remove(":contains('(Source:')");
$("p").remove(":contains('(source:')");
$("p").remove(":contains('(via ')");
});
</script>
<!--PARANAME VALUE FUNCTION CONTROLS-->
<style type="text/css">rel.body. rel.html</style><!-- RESET CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.tumblr.com/twte3d7/y4alvqlfs/prettyphoto.css"/>
<link href="http://static.tumblr.com/hcocigh/0nOmckwnf/jquery-animation-102412mph.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--css reset + structure--><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.tumblr.com/hcocigh/hznmcs47d/reset.css"><!--end css reset + structure-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.tumblr.com/hcocigh/mydm96vrh/unimpulsive.txt"></script>
<script>function displayResult(){document.getElementById("p1").style.visibility="visible";}</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.tumblr.com/uiqhh9x/UYAm6i0bc/like.js"></script>
<iframe id="likeiframe" style="display:none;"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.tumblr.com/7qdgtio/iQPmcn41r/likedbyunimpulsive.txt"></script>
<!-- END PARANAME VALUE FUNCTION CONTROLS-->

<meta name="viewport" content="width=800" />

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<div id="relative-header">
<div align="right"><a href="/"><img src="{PortraitURL-128}" class="img" width="90" style="border-radius:128px;"></a>
<div class="blogtitle" style="margin-left:3px;padding-top:6px;"><a href="/">{Title}</a></div>
<div class="blogtitle" style="color:#b05845;font-size:11pt;margin-left:3px;padding-bottom:6px;">
photography binnacle</div>

<p><div style="width:200px;margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:30px">{Description}<br>
<p>Soy Estrella Fugaz, 24 años
Actualmente: Siegen, Alemania
Hometown: Viña del Mar, Chile
 </p>
 <p style="margin-top:30"><a href="/">{text:home link title}</a>
<a href="/ask">{text:message link title}</a>
{block:iflinkonetitle}<a href="{text:link one}">{text:link one title}</a>{/block:iflinkonetitle}{block:iflinktwotitle}<a href="{text:link two}">{text:link two title}</a>{/block:iflinktwotitle}{block:iflinkthreetitle}<a href="{text:link three}">{text:link three title}</a>{/block:iflinkthreetitle}{block:iflinkfourtitle}<a href="{text:link four}">{text:link four title}</a>{/block:iflinkfourtitle}<a href="http://unimpulsive.tumblr.com/">theme</a></p>
</div> 


<div class="rent">

    <div id="colecciones" style="text-align:right;">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="/tagged/treshermanos" class="link">Estancia Tres Hermanos<p class="down">Tierra del Fuego, Chile - 01/2014</p></a></li>
    <li><a href="/tagged/domrepene2014" class="link">Verano<p class="down">Punta Cana, Rep. Dominicana - 2014</p></a></li>
    <li><a href="/tagged/licanray2014" class="link">Sunrise, Farm<p class="down">Lican Ray, Chile - 2014</p></a></li>
    <li><a href="/tagged/panccini2013" class="link">Cocina Natural<p class="down">Yumbel, Chile - 2013</p></a></li>
    <li><a href="/tagged/cetbiobio" class="link">Autosustentabilidad Ganja Escuela<p class="down">Yumbel, Chile - 2013</p></a></li>
    <li><a href="/tagged/festivalfemenino" class="link">Festival de Artes Femeninas<p class="down">Miraflores, Santiago, Chile - 2013</p></a></li>
    <li><a href="/tagged/Altiplano" class="link">Altiplanico<p class="down">Peru, Bolivia, Chile - 2013</p></a></li>
    <li><a href="/tagged/pinguineras" class="link">Pingüineras Seno Otway<p class="down">Punta Arenas, Chile - 2013</p></a></li>
    <li><a href="/tagged/parenas2013" class="link">Colores del Atardecer<p class="down">Punta Arenas, Chile - 2013</p></a></li>
    <li><a href="/tagged/Hogar" class="link">El Hogar<p class="down"> Chile - 2013</p></a></li>
    <li><a href="/tagged/tallerled" class="link">Taller LED<p class="down">Playa Ancha, Chile - 2012</p></a></li>
    <li><a href="/tagged/campana" class="link">Cerro La Campana<p class="down">V Región, Chile - 2012</p></a></li>
    <li><a href="/tagged/costa" class="link">La Costa/ Coastline<p class="down">V Región, Chile - 2013</p></a></li>
    <li><a href="/tagged/fitocosmetica" class="link">Taller de Fitocosmética Natural<p class="down">Quillota, Chile - 2012</p></a></li>
    <li><a href="/tagged/inviernomagallanico" class="link">Paseo de invierno Magallánico<p class="down">Punta Arenas, Chile - 2013</p></a></li>
    <li><a href="/tagged/veranosur" class="link">Verano Sureño<p class="down">LicanRay, Villarica, Chile - 2013</p></a></li>
    <li><a href="/tagged/blanconegromagallanes" class="link">B&W Magallanes<p class="down">Punta Anreas, Chile - 2013</p></a></li>
    <li><a href="/tagged/Algarrobo" class="link">Costa Tranquila<p class="down">Algarrobo, Chile - 2013</p></a></li>

    </ul>
    </div>

</div>

</div></div>

<div class="header">
<div class="left">
<div id="posts">
{block:Posts}
<div class="entry">

{block:Text}
{block:Title}<span class="title">{Title}</span>{/block:Title}<span class="entrytext">{Body}</span>{block:IndexPage}<div id="text">
</div>
{/block:IndexPage}
{/block:Text}

{block:Link}
<a href="{URL}" class="title">{Name}</a>
{block:Description}{Description}{/block:Description}{block:IndexPage}<div id="text">
<a href="{Permalink}">POSTED {TimeAgo} &nbsp;//&nbsp; {NoteCountwithlabel} &nbsp;//&nbsp; {24Hour}:{Minutes} {AmPm}</a></div>
{/block:IndexPage}
{block:Link}

{block:Photo}
{block:IndexPage}<div id="shadow"><img style="opacity:.7;z-index:99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999;height:20px;width:375px;" src="http://28.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lpn6kseZUG1qm57imo1_500.png"/></div>
{block:IndexPage}
<div class="cooper" align="center"><a href="{ReblogURL}"><img src="http://static.tumblr.com/7qdgtio/MZSmcq8xk/reblog-ut.png" width="19" style="margin-top:3px;margin-left:0.5px;"></a>
</div><div class="j"><a id="like{PostID}" href="javascript:likelink('{PostID}','{Permalink}','');"><img src="http://static.tumblr.com/lba83dv/OUUltd958/spacer.gif" width="21" height="20" alt="Like this post" id="likeimage{PostID}"/></a></div><a href="{PhotoURL-HighRes}"  rel="prettyPhoto" title="{PhotoAlt}"><div class="jill"></div></a>{/block:indexpage}
<div class="img">
{Block:IndexPage}<center>{LinkOpenTag}<a href="{permalink}"><img src="{PhotoURL-500}" alt="{PhotoAlt}" width="380"></a>{LinkCloseTag}</center>{/block:indexpage}
{Block:PermalinkPage}<center><img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" alt="{PhotoAlt}"width=785px/></center>{/Block:PermalinkPage}
</div>
{/block:Photo}

{block:Photoset}
{block:IndexPage}<div id="shadow"><img style="opacity:.7;z-index:99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999;height:20px;width:250px;" src="http://28.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lpn6kseZUG1qm57imo1_500.png"/></div>
{block:IndexPage}
<div class="cooper" align="center"><a href="{ReblogURL}"><img src="http://static.tumblr.com/7qdgtio/MZSmcq8xk/reblog-ut.png" width="19" style="margin-top:3px;margin-left:0.5px;"></a>
</div><div class="j"><a id="like{PostID}" href="javascript:likelink('{PostID}','{Permalink}','');"><img src="http://static.tumblr.com/lba83dv/OUUltd958/spacer.gif" width="21" height="20" alt="Like this post" id="likeimage{PostID}"/></a></div><a href="{PhotoURL-HighRes}"  rel="prettyPhoto" title="{PhotoAlt}"><div class="jill"></div></a>{/block:indexpage}
<div class="img">
{block:indexpage}
<center>{Photoset-250}</center>
{/block:indexpage}
{block:PermalinkPage}<center>{Photoset-HighRes}</center>{/block:PermalinkPage}
</div>
{/block:Photoset}

{block:Quote}
<span class="quoted">“</span><div class="quote-style">{Quote}</div><div class="quote-indention"><p>- {Source}</p></div>{block:IndexPage}<div id="text">
<a href="{Permalink}">POSTED {TimeAgo} &nbsp;//&nbsp; {NoteCountwithlabel} &nbsp;//&nbsp; {24Hour}:{Minutes} {AmPm}</a></div>
{/block:IndexPage}
{/block:Quote}

{block:Chat}
{block:Title}
<div class="title"><a href="{Permalink}">{Title}</a></div>
{/block:Title}
<div class="chat ul">
{block:Lines}
<li class="{Alt} user_{UserNumber}">
{block:Label}<span class="label">{Label}</span>{/block:Label} {Line}</li>
{/block:Lines}</div></li>
{block:IndexPage}<div id="text">
<a href="{Permalink}">POSTED {TimeAgo} &nbsp;//&nbsp; {NoteCountwithlabel} &nbsp;//&nbsp; {24Hour}:{Minutes} {AmPm}</a></div>
{/block:IndexPage}
{/block:Chat}

{block:Audio}
<center><div style="width:250px; background-color:#E3E3E3; height:28px;"><div style="float:left;left:0px;">{AudioPlayerGrey}<img style="margin-top:-1px;width:{block:IndexPage}250px{/block:IndexPage}{block:PermalinkPage}500px{/block:PermalinkPage};opacity:.7;" src="http://28.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lpn6kseZUG1qm57imo1_500.png"/></div><div style="margin-top:10px; float:right;">
{block:ExternalAudio}{/block:ExternalAudio}</div></div></center>{block:IndexPage}<div id="text">
<a href="{Permalink}">POSTED {TimeAgo} &nbsp;//&nbsp; {NoteCountwithlabel} &nbsp;//&nbsp; {24Hour}:{Minutes} {AmPm}</a></div>
{/block:IndexPage}
{/block:Audio}

{block:Video}
{block:IndexPage}
<center>
{Video-250}</center>
{/block:IndexPage}
{block:PermalinkPage}{Video-500}{/block:PermalinkPage}
{block:IndexPage}<div id="text">
<a href="{Permalink}">POSTED {TimeAgo} &nbsp;//&nbsp; {NoteCountwithlabel} &nbsp;//&nbsp; {24Hour}:{Minutes} {AmPm}</a></div>
{/block:IndexPage}
{block:Video}

{block:Answer}
<div id="ask"><img src="{AskerPortraitURL-30}" width="30" align="left" style="margin-right:3px;"/></div>
<b>{Asker}</b>: <b>{Question}</b>{Answer}{block:IndexPage}<div id="text">
<a href="{Permalink}">POSTED {TimeAgo} &nbsp;//&nbsp; {NoteCountwithlabel} &nbsp;//&nbsp; {24Hour}:{Minutes} {AmPm}</a></div>
{/block:IndexPage}
{/block:Answer}


{block:PermalinkPage}<div class="posted-rel">{block:Date}{TimeAgo} | {12HourWithZero}:{Minutes}{AmPm}<br>{block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}{block:NoteCount}{NoteCountWithLabel}{/block:NoteCount}{block:HasTags} &middot; {block:Tags}<a href="TagURL"> #{Tag}</a> {/block:Tags}{/block:hasTags}{/block:Date}</div>{/block:PermalinkPage}

{block:PostNotes}<div id="post_notes">{PostNotes}</div>{/block:PostNotes}
</div>

{/block:Posts}
</div>

</div>


<div class="footer">
<br>
</div>
</div>

<div class="rightmenu">
<div id="tagCloud"></div><script type="text/javascript" src="//post-theory.com/public/tagcloud/bitacora-fotografica?tn={Name}&sort=time&limit=20&mincount=2&scale=false&fontsize=10px&html=ulplain&pad=4&tagct=%20(%24)&scalect=false" async="async"></script>
</div>

</body>
</html>
<div style="position:fixed;right:0px;bottom:-425px;">
<---DONT REMOVE---->
{block:IndexPage}
{block:Pagination}
<div id="pagination">
{block:NextPage}
<a id="nextPage" href="{NextPage}">&nbsp;&rarr;</a>
{/block:NextPage}
{block:PreviousPage}
<a href="{PreviousPage}">&larr;&nbsp;</a>
{/block:PreviousPage}
</div>
{/block:Pagination}
{/block:IndexPage}</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: hi @Estrella welcome to stackoverflow kindly post only short snippet of code to rapidly check your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Do u know about `JavaSCript` ?? 
you can do it with `JavaScript` by using `window.onunload` event

check out here is what yo want :)

http://jsbin.com/zezaxe/1/edit?html,js

Comment: The thing is that the hover is already activated by css, but somehow not working right, so I want to fix that instead of adding stuff to it